# Python: split string by closing bracket and write in new line

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
This is one sentence()This is another sentence()This is a full sentence at all)Maybe this too)This is the last sentence()
```

I need to split the parts that the text looks like this:

```
This is one sentence()
This is another sentence()
This is a full sentence at all)
Maybe this too)
This is the last sentence()
```

I tried it with regex and the help of https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/5#python but I can't find any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex just [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) any closing paren with a closing paren followed by a newline:

```
s="This is one sentence()This is another sentence()This is a full sentence at all)Maybe this too)This is the last sentence()"

print(s.replace(")",")\n"))
```

Output:

```
This is one sentence()
This is another sentence()
This is a full sentence at all)
Maybe this too)
This is the last sentence()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search using this lookbehind regex:

```
r'(?<=\))'
```

and replace by `"\n"`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/76)

**Code:**

```
input = u"This is one sentence()This is another sentence()This is a full sentence at all)Maybe this too)This is the last sentence()"

result = re.sub(ur'(?<=\))', "\n", input)
```